# Immer.js and eslint fp/no-mutation

Tags: javascript, immer.js

Eslint always complains about `Unallowed reassignment` from `fp/no-mutation` rule for basic `immer` construct:

```
const nextState = produce(baseState, draftState => {
    draftState.push({todo: "Tweet about it"})
    draftState[1].done = true
})
```

Since draftState is always being mutated, how can this annoyance be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an exception for **fp/no-mutation** rule in the ESLint configuration.

```
"fp/no-mutation": [
   "error",
   {
     exceptions: [{ object: "draftState" }],
   },
 ]
```

**Note**: This would just suffice for the case when the mutating object is "draftState". So you'd have to keep that in mind :)

**Reference:** https://github.com/jfmengels/eslint-plugin-fp/blob/master/docs/rules/no-mutation.md